# Passing a variable to an anonymous function without using the use keyword

Tags: php, dependency-injection

I have a `Router` class:

```
$router->
    get($pattern, $callback); // creates a new route
    [...]
```

And an `Application` class:

```
$app->
    get($pattern, $callback); // calls the router `get()` method
    [...]
```

The problem is, when I'm setting the callback, inside each function I need the `$app` instance. I know I can use the `use` keyword, but using it for every route, every callback will by annoying and pointless.

Example:

Change:

```
$app->get('here/is/my/pattern', function () use ($app) {
    $app->controller('just_an_example');
});
```

To:

```
$app->get('here/is/my/pattern', function () {
    $app->controller('just_an_example');
});
```

How can I pass a variable to an anonymous function without the `use` keyword?

Comment: The only thing I can think of off hand is rebinding the callback to `$app`.

Comment: Are you using Silex? That has one huge Application object and this looks similar.

Comment: @Jimbo No, but I'm very inspired by this framework. :)

Comment: @Bartek In case you want more inspiration, I love Silex but it had some bad practices. I integrated Doctrine ORM and a recursively instantiating Dependency Injection container, meaning you can just typehint for any object in your Controller methods and it'll automatically be passed in for you. Here's [Auryn](https://github.com/rdlowrey/Auryn), and here's the [Lib](https://github.com/J7mbo/silex-auth-skeleton) in case you're interested.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your design is wrong.

It is not the Router's job to call the Controller. Instead, your Router should `return` something (usually a `Route` object) the corresponds to the match route. Generally like so:

```
$router = new Router($reuqest->getURI()); //The request URI
$router->addRoute("some/pattern", "SomeController");
$router->addRoute("some/other/pattern", "SomeOtherController");
$route = $router->route(); //$route now has a Route object.

$controllerClass = $route->getResource();
$app->$controllerClass($request); //Pass the Request object with GET and POST and whatever into the controller
```

This way, the router doesn't know it goes to some controller, and the controller doesn't know it came from a route. The two components are now completely reusable.

Comment: I'm doing the same thing that you, the only difference is that I use closures and pass the `$router` instance directly in the `$app` instance.

Before I have a similar design to yours, my problem was that my router was very huge and somebody says me that the Router should not be the 'main' class, so I'm doing a sort of wrapper for the Router and other components I need to execute the entire application (like Silex does).

I'm also calling the controller in application class, I just use router to match the route I need.

Comment: Your components should be separate. Think about it this way: "What if I wanted to extract the Router and use it in a different project?" It's best to create modules which has very few to no external dependencies. What does the Router I made depends on? The URI, which will always exist in HTTP context, and the Route object, which is a part of the module. **THAT'S IT**. Your ***application*** depends on your Router, but the Router ***should not depend on your application***.

Comment: How is this answer answering the original question?

Comment: It isn't a solution to OP's XY problem, but it is the solution to the actual problem.

Answer (score 2):

### Short Answer

Just `use` in the variable.

### Long Answer

Seriously, just `use` the variable.

### Alternate Answer

You *could* rebind the callback, if it's a closure:

```
function rebind(App $app, Closure $closure) {
    return $closure->bindTo($app);
}

$app->get('here/is/my/pattern', rebind($app, function () {
    $this->controller('just_an_example');
}));
```

`$this` is now bound to `$app`, and `$this` is always available in the scope of a non-static closure.

But that isn't gaining you much aside from unnecessary indirection; please refer to the **Short Answer** and/or **Long Answer**.

Comment: Using the `use` keyword I'll make the `$app` instance a sort of a global variable, so should I?

Comment: It's not a global variable at all. It's a variable that's been "closed over" and introduced to the scope of the closure; it can only come from the parent scope.